# AWS Lambda-multiple suffix -error creating the event source mapping: Configuration is ambiguously defined

Tags: aws-lambda

Im trying to create event is multiple Suffix (.json/.avro)
There was an error creating the event source mapping: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Amazon currently does not allow multiple overlapping triggers to start a Lambda. The only work around available is to create a single trigger which publishes to an SNS topic, and then have that SNS topic "fan out" to a number of destinations.

[image]